# [1][2][3]Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3 at Matrices.main(Matrices.java:19)

Tags: java

I'm doing a course of java and I tried to do this exercise without help, but my cdm says to me:

[1][2][3]Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3         at Matrices.main(Matrices.java:19)﻿
Even so, I copied the exercise of my teacher and he didn't have any mistake. Help me please. Thanks.

My exercise:

```
 import java.util.Scanner;
    public class Matrices{
     public static void main(String args[]){

       int contador = 1, filas = 0, columnas = 0;
       Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);

       System.out.println("¿Cuantas filas quiere?");
       filas = entrada.nextInt();

       System.out.println("¿Cuantas columnas quiere?");
       columnas = entrada.nextInt();

       int matriz1 [][] = new int [filas][columnas];

      for(int j = 0; j < filas; j++){
        for(int i = 0; i < columnas; j++){
          matriz1[j][i] = contador;
          contador++;
          System.out.print("[" + matriz1[j][i] + "]");  
        }
         System.out.println("");
       }    
     }
    }
```

My teacher exercise:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MatricesDinamicas{
  public static void main(String args[]){

   int filas = 0, columnas = 0, contador = 1;
   Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);

   System.out.println("¿Cuantas filas deseas?");
   filas = entrada.nextInt();

   System.out.println("¿Cuantas columnas deseas?");
   columnas = entrada.nextInt();

   int numeros [][] = new int [filas][columnas];

   for(int j = 0; j < filas; j++){
    for(int i = 0; i < columnas; i++){
      numeros[j][i] = contador;
      contador++;
      System.out.print("[" + numeros[j][i] + "]");
    }
     System.out.println("");
   }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're incrementing `j` in `i`'s loop:

```
for(int j = 0; j < filas; j++) {
  for(int i = 0; i < columnas; i++) {
      // Was j in the OP ------^
```

Comment: That's right. Thanks so much.